# How do I add active class to parent of li that i selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$(function() {
    var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
            .lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    $("#nav ul ul li a").each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '')
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
    });

});
```

here is the js I am using

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="headerFont"><a href="index.jsp"><b>HOME</b></a></li>
        <li class="headerFont"><a href="link.jsp"><b>HOW TO
                    DONATE</b></a></li>
        <li class="headerFont"><a href="#"><b>DONATE</b></a>         <----- AND THIS SINCE SHOULD
            <ul>                                                            ALSO BE ACTIVE
                <li class="headerFont"><a href="link2.jsp"><b>DONATION    <----- IF I SELECT THIS
                            CENTER <img id="arrow" src="img/arrow.png" />     IT SHOULD BE ACTIVE
                    </b></a></li>
                <li class="headerFont"><a href="link3.jsp"><b>HOW ELSE
                            CAN I DONATE? <img id="arrow" src="img/arrow.png" />
                    </b></a></li>
            </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

when I select li without sub-li it works fine. but when I select li that are inside other li, It makes the child li active but not the parent. If I want to make the parent active also, for example, If i select "Donation Center" which is inside "Donate". what should I add or change in order to make the "Donate" li also active?

Comment: You want to make both the parent `li` active, or just the top most?

Comment: Play around with `$(this).closest('li').addClass('active').parents('li').addClass('active')`, it will look for all ancestors `li` elements and give it the class `active`. Might help.

Comment: @LcSalazar both would be better

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried using the method children? May it could be useful for you.

I would change your code for this one:

```
$("#nav ul ul").children("li").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find("a").attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).find("a").attr("href") == '')
        $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

[See more information about method children here](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Answer (score 0):

There's a Jquery method for almost every nested elements interation you can imagine...

In you case, the most suitable would be [**jQuery's .parentsUntil()**](http://api.jquery.com/parentsuntil/).

As the name states, it will select every parent until a selector condition is met. As an optional second parameter, you can filter the results, narrowing the selection to just the type of element that you want.

So, you would have something like:

```
$(this).parentsUntil("#nav > ul", "li").addClass("active");
```

This would target every parent `li` until it reaches the top most `ul`.

Comment: just tried it. still the same, still only the child gets the active class... can you give me some sample?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

> $("#nav").on("click","li",function() {
>               $(this).addClass('active');
>           });

That will add the active class to the `li` clicked and the `li` parent.